# how weather temprature of a particular city can be shown on my asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how i can show weather temperatue on my webpage just like yahoo website. i want to show the temprature of a particular city.

aspx code

```
<div style="position:absolute;height:705px; background-color:#49A3FF; width:214px;  top: 171px; left: 1067px;"  id="bodyright">

</div>
```

i want to show temprature in this tag. i searched allot from google i found it use Google API but i couldn't understand how to use Google API. kindly please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://openweathermap.org/current
There is a complete API description including examples.

Send a request with the city name or city id. The answer is a JSON string.

Example:
[https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid={APIKEY}](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=%7BAPIKEY%7D)

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 4.4035,
    "lat": 51.2199
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 2.08,
    "feels_like": 2.08,
    "temp_min": 0.47,
    "temp_max": 3.34,
    "pressure": 1022,
    "humidity": 77
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 0.89,
    "deg": 124,
    "gust": 3.13
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 0
  },
  "dt": 1640181856,
  "sys": {
    "type": 2,
    "id": 2006860,
    "country": "BE",
    "sunrise": 1640159088,
    "sunset": 1640187429
  },
  "timezone": 3600,
  "id": 2803138,
  "name": "Antwerp",
  "cod": 200
}
```

The temperature in the response is "Kelvin". To get Celsius, use units=metric
[https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&units=metric&appid={APIKEY}](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&units=metric&appid=%7BAPIKEY%7D)

The temperature in the response is "Kelvin". To get Fahrenheit, use units=imperial
[https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&units=imperial&appid={APIKEY}](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&units=imperial&appid=%7BAPIKEY%7D)

Comment: how i can embed this to my webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Microsoft** free web service to get temperature of any city in the World.

[Here](http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather) is the link you should visit. There are a lot of ways to call the service mentioned on the page.

**Example:**

A simplest method to call it:

http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=Karachi&CountryName=Pakistan

**Explanation:**

In the above example:

**CityName** = Karachi

**CountryName** = Pakistan

Just change the city and country name to use it as you need.

**Code:**

```
//call webservice using HTTP get method
var xml = XDocument.Load("http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetWeather?CityName=Karachi&CountryName=Pakistan");

//convert it to xml
string response = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(xml.ToString());
```

The XML response you will get:

```
<string xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> 
    <CurrentWeather> 
        <Location>Karachi Airport, Pakistan (OPKC) 24-54N 067-08E 22M</Location> 
        <Time>Jul 16, 2014 - 01:25 AM EDT / 2014.07.16 0525 UTC</Time> 
        <Wind> from the WSW (240 degrees) at 9 MPH (8 KT):0</Wind> 
        <Visibility> 3 mile(s):0</Visibility> 
        <SkyConditions> mostly cloudy</SkyConditions> 
        <Temperature> 87 F (31 C)</Temperature> 
        <DewPoint> 75 F (24 C)</DewPoint> 
        <RelativeHumidity> 66%</RelativeHumidity> 
        <Pressure> 29.44 in. Hg (0997 hPa)</Pressure> 
        <Status>Success</Status> 
    </CurrentWeather>
</string>
```

Comment: please write down the step what i have to do. how i can add these services

Comment: where and in which file i will add this code.. please help me

Comment: how XML can be added in my webpage? and how temprature will be shown on my website?

Comment: You will just need to create an http request to the URL you will creating manually a/c to the city and country. and then you will have to parse the response you will get to show on your page.

Comment: right click>project name>add web refferences>url>click go. this process will be followed?

Comment: which URL i will write there?

Comment: No this is not the way to call a webservice. You do everything by programming. I am updating my answer, keep patience until its done.

Comment: how much time is required?

Comment: I was a little busy. just 5 more minutes.

Comment: @Shaharyar You want to perform this request on the client (JS), that way loading weather information does not increase the page's load time, especially in cases when the weather service is not available for any reason.

Comment: But the question tagged with `C#`, not `js`.

Comment: thanks a lot :) i want to show 3 cities temprature at the same time. your code will solve this problem. for example i want to show the temprature of gujranwala,gujrat and sialkot. these are the cities whose temprature i have to show

Comment: see this site http://hamariweb.com/ at bottom they have shown the temprature of 3 cities i have to make just like that

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/153911-c%23using-google-weather-api-in-a-c%23-application/. It is a complete example of using google api with C#. Follow this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You could use Yahoo weather service.  No need to register or anything.

Here's an example updating your HTML with JS, it also keep's the temperature updated every 4 minutes in case your user leaves the browser window open without refreshing...

```
var dest$ = $('#bodyright'),
    woeid = 2211096;

var updateWeather = function() {
    $.getJSON('//query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?format=json&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent('select item from weather.forecast where woeid=' + woeid + ''), function(data) {
        if (data && data['query'] && data['query']['results'] && data['query']['results']['channel'] && data['query']['results']['channel']['item'] && data['query']['results']['channel']['item']['condition']) {
           var wInfo = data['query']['results']['channel']['item']['condition'];

           $('<span></span>')
               .appendTo(dest$.append('<br/>'))
               .text('Temp: ' + wInfo['temp'] + ' F');

           // last updated...:
           $('<span></span>')
               .appendTo(dest$.append('<br/>'))
               .text('Last Updated: ' + wInfo['date']);

           // yahoo weather image can be loaded using (yimg_we/' + wInfo['code'] + '.gif'), cant remember URL...
           $('<img/>').attr({
                'src': 'https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/121210/' + wInfo['code'] + '.png',
                'alt': wInfo['text'],
                'title': wInfo['text']
            }).appendTo(dest$.append('<br/>'));
        }
    });
    setTimeout(updateWeather, 240000);
};
setTimeout(updateWeather, 50);
```

Comment: i embed this code in head tag but nothing displayed :(

Comment: Place in `$(function() { <code from above> });` or in a `<script></script>` tag below the `<div .. id="bodyright"></div>`

Comment: i write all above code like this <div><script>code from above</script></div>

Comment: Check your web browser debugging console for requests to query.yahooapis.com.

Comment: Also, the code above depends on the jQuery JS library.

Comment: i just know how to debug the cs file not aspx file.

Comment: Press F12 in your browser and look at the console for client side debugging information.

Comment: got it :) thanks a lot. temp have shown but no image. how can i apply image just like in yahoo site

Comment: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. this is an error

Comment: Module IIS Web Core
Notification MapRequestHandler
Handler StaticFile
Error Code 0x80070002

Comment: Updated to include yahoo image.  Note how I used the URL 'https://s.yimg.com/dh/ap/default/121210/' for the location of the images.

Comment: Temp: 72 FLast Updated: Wed, 16 Jul 2014 3:25 am EDT this is an output of your code. is it right?

Comment: Yes, in this example it is using zip code 10005.  You'll want to update this the zip code of your city.  If you only have city/country, the yql query will have to be adjusted.

Comment: i want to show particular city temp.  i have to show 3 cities temprature individualy at the same time

Comment: see this site http://hamariweb.com/ at bottom they have shown 3 cities temprature i have to made just like that.

Comment: To use Yahoo weather, you'll have to have each city's WOEID.  This can be obtained from the URL after searching for the city at https://weather.yahoo.com/.  For example, the WOEID for Karachi, PK is 2211096.  I've updated the code above to load the weather using WOEID 2211096.